# Angular checkbox not visible using mat-checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to display checkbox inside angular UI

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "item.role" [checked]="false"> 
  <label>IT Admin</label> 
</mat-checkbox>
```

I have attached image below and if I tried to create style for mat-checkbox the style is applied including label.[image]

Comment: Hi, 
change the binding [checked]="false" to [checked]="item.role", 
I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: When the check box is not clicked the box is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is applied to the label because the label is inside of the mat-checkbox tag. Try separating them and using a form group if you can.

`<div class="form-group">
   <label for="role">IT Admin</label>
   <mat-checkbox id="role" [(ngModel)]="item.role" [checked]="item.role"></mat-checkbox>
</div>`

This is under the assumption that you are using forms.

Comment: Hi Nick, I don't have concern on label, I want the checkbox to be displayed even if it is not clicked

Comment: Oh, I see. I misunderstood the question. have you tried adding a class with a border to the mat-checkbox like <mat-checkbox class="something" ...>

Comment: Thank You I am able to style the check box alone now

Comment: May be worth noting that MatCheckboxModule should be imported into app.module.ts ,  later versions of Angular may not call out error if it's missing.

Comment: @karansys: plz provide your solution.